# Error while running ./network.sh down. Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Stopping network

ERROR: Version in "./docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version ("2.0", "2.1", "3.0", "3.1", "3.2") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

ERROR: Version in "./addOrg3/docker/docker-compose-couch-org3.yaml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version ("2.0", "2.1", "3.0", "3.1", "3.2") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Removing remaining containers

Removing generated chaincode docker images

**My version:**

$docker-compose
version

docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e

docker-py version: 2.3.0

CPython version: 2.7.13

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be tagged under `docker-compose`, not `hyperledger-fabric`.

The problem is in your `./docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml`, which you do not attach. As the error suggests, your docker-compose version is [1.14](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1140), which supports versions ["2.0", "2.1", "3.0", "3.1", "3.2"], but you specify another another one in that file (let's imagine that it is `version '2.4'`). You should specify a supported version (and check that the syntax is still correct) or upgrade docker-compose in your system.

Comment: Oh thank you. Worked changing the compose to 1.23.2.